How to migrate WSL2 to Jupyter Notebooks for cuDF?
I finally successfully installed rapids onto my WSL2 for the purpose of using cuDF to multithread my GPU in python, so now the remaining task is to be able to use a Jupyter Notebook instead of the obviously inconvenient WSL2 window. The problem is that when I open a Jupyter Notebook via WSL2, I can't import cuDF anymore. I hypothesize the reason for this is one or more of the following:

The Jupyter Notebooks being opened from WSL2 is- for some reason- the same Jupyter Notebooks that would have been opened if i had just clicked on my "Jupyter Notebooks" from my desktop.
The conda environment created from conda activate rapids-24.06 is not the environment in the opened Jupyter Notebook.
Copying the link somehow destroys the server, since it does say, " Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation)". How else could I possibly copy the URLs to open up the notebook, though?

I also followed the steps in this article, https://code.adonline.id.au/jupyter-notebook-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/, but the article doesn't write as though the problem I'm having is a possibility.
Steps I took to get where I'm at after following the article:

Open WSL2
conda activate rapids-24.06
jupyter notebook
I'm provided with 3 URLs:
a. First URL "file:///home/ ...html" just leads me to a File Not Found error
b. Second Link just leads me to 500 : Internal Server Error
c. 3rd Link just leads me to 500 : Internal Server Error
Sometimes one of the three links will lead me to a Jupyter Notebook, but when that does happen, cuDF can't be imported; I must be in a different conda environment (and of course, when I command !conda activate rapids-24.06, the environment isn't found).

Obviously I would love to know why sometimes these links in step 4 don't work at all. Any help will be appreciated. Below is the image of what the window looks like when I receive the 500 : Internal Server Error. I don't think it looks any different when one of the links is able to bring me to Jupyter Notebooks- sorry I can't recreate it "working" for some reason.

Appreciate the help

I suspect the global install of jupyter lab does not have access to the conda env. Can you try installing jupyterlab within the conda environment. After the installation which jupyter command should display the correct path within the conda env for jupyter.
This should hopefully resolve the issue
